# invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '. sigh

Tags: python-3.x

beginner here so be kind.

This is my example code.

`def iq_test(numbers): for i in numbers: if int(i) %2 != 0: return i`

This bit of code always returns the invalid literal for base10... which is weird as when the mod operator is == 0, it doesn't return the error. Where am I going wrong?

I've tried .isdigit, tried to use a float instead but no joy.

Comment: What are you passing in as `numbers` argument? Is is string-like?

Comment: Please post the actual code with indentation. See [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stated what your requirement is, so I will guess that it is to "extract the first odd number from a string containing a mixture of numbers and letters".

You also wonder why i % 2 == 0 allows some specific test to work, but that might only be because the string being tested only contains even numbers.

Here is your function adjusted to answer that hypothetical question:

```
def iq_test(numbers):
    for i in numbers:
        if str(i).isdigit() and int(i) %2 != 0:
            return i
```

Note the stringify requirement for testing each element of the string/list as integer.

Comment: That's perfect, you're quite right, i'm trying to find an odd number in  a list, well, string of numbers.  The base 10 error is a really difficult one to understand. Ah, as it goes, that code doesn' work either. if this is the str on numbers; "2 4 7 8 10" it still returns the base 10 error.

Comment: With that string value of `'2 4 7 8 10'` it does work, returns 7